# How far can the human eye see?

Tags: biophysics, vision

This question has already been asked but the answers are old and the links no longer work.
I'm interested in the answer but even more in research papers that have shown the answer.

Comment: Some people can see the Andromeda Galaxy.

Comment: the milky way is quite visible, the important issue is not distance but angular resolution and given the pupil size and spherical aberration the resolution is about 20 (theoretical) to 60 (practical) arcsec.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77813/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122785/2451

Comment: I was intrigued by the broken link, and by searching I found a dr Tom Salmon in the univesity nsuok.edu . I think that his "in this famous paper: " is an ironical reference to some lecture notes of his, not a published paper. If he went to another university his user page was disabled so the link is broken. Also the user who posted the link has more than a year to appear at this site,